# adding an iterator to my arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyArrayList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
    public static final int EXPANSION = 5;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private Object[] items;

    public MyArrayList() {
        size = 0;
        capacity = DEFAULT_SIZE;
        items = new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    }

    private void expand() {
        Object[] newItems = new Object[capacity + EXPANSION];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) newItems[j] = items[j];
        items = newItems;
        capacity = capacity + EXPANSION;
    }

    public void add(Object obj) {
        if (size >= capacity) this.expand();
        items[size] = obj;
        size++;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        try{
            return items[index];
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Thrown: " + "Index is out of bound");
            }
            return index;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (obj.equals(this.get(j))) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void add(int index, Object obj) {
        try{
            if (size >= capacity) this.expand();
            for (int j = size; j > index; j--) items[j] = items[j - 1];
            items[index] = obj;
            size++;
              } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Thrown: " + "Index is out of bound");
              }
            return;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object obj) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (obj.equals(this.get(j))) return j;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object obj) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (obj.equals(this.get(j))) {
                for (int k = j; k < size-1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
                size--;
                items[size] = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Object remove(int index) {
        try{
            Object result = this.get(index);
            for (int k = index; k < size-1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
            items[size] = null;
            size--;
            return result;
             } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Thrown: " + "Index is out of bound");
              }
            return index;
    }

    public void set(int index, Object obj) {
        try{
            items[index] = obj;
             } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Thrown: " + "Index is out of bound");
             }
            return;
    }




public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return new MyIterator<E>();
}

public class MyIterator <T> implements Iterator<T>{
    public boolean hasNext(){

    }

public T next(){

}

public void remove(){

    }
}


}
```

Basically I'm trying to improve the functionality of my arraylist, as it uses for loops for methods such as add and remove, however I am trying to use an iterator instead and I searched it up and I found out you cannot just simply add implements iterable to the main class, it has to be implemented by using three methods next(), hasNext() and remove(). I added the three methods at the bottom of the code but i'm really not sure how I implement it in order for it to begin to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (NOTE: I have not tried to compile this or anything so please update this post if you find any errors!)

```
public class MyArrayList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    ...

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>() {
            private Object[] currentData = items;
            private int pos = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return pos < currentData.length;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                return (E) currentData[pos++];
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                MyArrayList.this.remove(pos++);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much that was the only problem in my code I didnt put return (E)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to keep track of the index in the `items` array that the `Iterator` is on. Let's call it `int currentIndex`. `hasNext()` will return `true` if `currentIndex < size`. `next()` will increment `currentIndex` if `hasNext()` is `true` and return `items[currentIndex]`, otherwise it should throw an `Exception`, say `NoSuchElementException`. Remove will call `remove(currentIndex)`.

Comment: thank you for your help as well I was able to understand it more

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `items` array to your `MyIterator` class so that you can keep track of the current position of the cursor in the array. Now based on the current position of the cursor you could implement all the abstract methods.

In the constructor of the `MyIterator` class pass the array as a parameter as `public MyIterator(E[] array)` and store the array as a local variable. also create a local variable cursor and set its value to 0.

Comment: i'm a beginner at this so sorry if its a stupid question, how exactly do I pass items array to my iterator class

Comment: Ok I will give the details.